# having issues with school assignment

Tags: c++

there are some crash bugs in this code that i am supposed to find but i am having issues finding them i have spent quite awhile looking. i am sure that it is something easy that i am missing. when i run the code in visual studio 2012 i get and array subscript error

```
#include <iostream> // provides access to cin and cout
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

#include <vector>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // seed random number generator
    srand(time(NULL));

enum symbol
{
    Lemon, Cherry, Orange, Bell, Jackpot
};
// create a struct for slot machine wheel
struct Wheel
{
    array <string, 10> symbols;
    array <symbol, 10> eSymbols;
    int position;
    string selected;
};
//create an array of three slot machine wheels
array <Wheel, 3> slotMachine =
{
    {
        { 
            {"Cherry", "Orange", "Lemon", "Orange", "Bell", "Orange",    "Lemon", "Cherry", "Jackpot", "Bell"},
            {Cherry, Orange, Lemon, Orange, Bell, Orange, Lemon,Cherry, Jackpot, Bell},
            0,"Cherry"
        },
        {
            {"Cherry", "Bell", "Lemon", "Orange", "Bell", "Jackpot", "Lemon", "Cherry", "Jackpot", "Bell"},
            {Cherry, Bell, Lemon, Orange, Bell, Jackpot, Lemon, Cherry, Jackpot, Bell},
            1,"Bell"
            },
            {
                {"Cherry", "Orange", "Lemon", "Orange", "Lemon", "Orange", "Lemon","Cherry", "Jackpot", "Bell"},
                {Cherry, Orange, Lemon, Orange, Lemon, Orange, Lemon, Cherry, Jackpot, Bell},
                2,"Lemon"
            }
    }
};

bool gameOn = true;
bool winner = false;
int thePot = 100;
int bet = 1;
vector <int> combo;
while (gameOn)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        slotMachine[i].position =(slotMachine[i].position + rand()%10)%10;
        slotMachine[i].selected = slotMachine[i].symbols[slotMachine[i].position];
        cout << setw(10) << left << slotMachine[i].selected.c_str() ;
        combo.push_back(slotMachine[i].eSymbols[slotMachine[i].position]);
    }
    if ((combo[0] == combo[1]) && (combo[1] == combo[2]))
    {
        if (combo[0] == Lemon)
        {
            cout << "You keep your bet." << endl;
        }
        else if(combo[0] = Jackpot)
        {
            cout << "**** You hit $1000 Jackpot!!! ****" << endl;
            thePot += 1000;
            winner = true;
            gameOn = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "WINNER! You win $" << combo[0]*5 << endl;
            thePot += combo[0]*5;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        thePot -= bet;
        if (thePot > 0 ) gameOn=false;
    }
    cout << "You now have $" << thePot << endl;
    combo.clear();
    cout << endl;
    cin.get();
}
if (winner) cout << "You walk away a winner." << endl;
else cout << "You have lost all your money." << endl;
// Wait for user input to close program when debugging.
cin.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Is your SHIFT key broken, Levi? And do you think this question's title will help others find and be helped by the post, in the future?

Comment: Sorry for the way that I have posted this s my first time using this site and this is the first class that i have taken in programming. Thanks for the information about how to  debug small programs, it helped  a lot. I will make sure that my next post I provide more detail in what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a

```
array <Wheel, 3> slotMachine;
```

Afterwards you iterated through this array as follows:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    slotMachine[i].position =
```

This code will access `slotMachine[1]` through `slotMachine[3]`, according to the loop's logic.

Unfortunately, there is no `slotMachine[3]`, and an attempt to access it results in undefined behavior, and your likely crash.

An array or a vector of `N` elements contains elements numbered from 0 to `N-1`. You can use your fingers to verify this fact.

This array contains `slotMachine[0]` through `slotMachine[2]`, not `slotMachine[1]` through `slotMachine[3]`. That's how arrays and vectors work in C++.

Comment: Thank you for the help I knew it was something obvious but i have been staring at the screen for awhile doing other parts of this assignment. In the future I will be sure to check more carefully before posting to this site.